# Cannot open PDF file using Google Drive app

Tags: google-drive

My device is running on Android Oreo, and I have study notes as a PDF file on Google Drive ([link to the file for testing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XT0g2HAqcJIjpBroYQTELbXszclITajB/view)), but I can't open it on Google Drive app.

My file is not opening and it's saying "No connection" even though I've got an awesome connection. I don't know why it's not syncing my file.

> [image: 'No connection' is shown even though there's a transfer speed of 257KB/s shown on the notification status]

I've even cleared cache, refreshed my Google Drive, and also rebooted my phone.

How to fix this issue so that I can open my PDF file from Google Drive app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug with Google Drive. I had the same problem in opening the link

**Workaround**

I pasted the link in Chrome and it opened! You should [report the bug](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!categories/drive/android), also
in Playstore

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

To download the file, open Chrome in desktop mode and click the  option (print).

Answer (score 0):

What I do, because I have the same issue, I use Open With option works like a charm. I use the Google PDF Viewer

Comment: Oh, lol, but at that time I've got no other option s other than this